# How to scale correctly figure verticaly in the appendix?

Tags: floats

I want to put one picture in the appendix.

I tried different approaches but all the time my figure appears in the next pages. I also tried to set different size of figure but nevertheless the figure stays in the same page.

I want this figure be in the same page as appendix label and that the figure be in vertical position and the maximum as possible size.

I tried this code:

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Figures/2017_12_ElNino.pdf}%
\caption{Overall system setup}
\label{fig:2017_12_ElNino}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

My figure looks next:

[image]

I have tried `width=0.6` but the figure just stays on the previous page. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, environment `sidewaysfigure` goes to the next page by default (or maybe there is a `[h]` or even `[h!]` option, check the `rotating` [package documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rotating)).

A workaround would be to define a `minipage` with specific height, and scale the width of your rotated image to that height. See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\section{World map}
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{\textwidth}
\centering 
\begin{sideways}
\includegraphics[width=\textheight]{world.jpg}
\end{sideways}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image]